# babel CLI copy nonjs files

Tags: babeljs

I'm running a babel cli command

```
babel src --out-dir lib
```

To copy the es6 scripts from src into lib. However, it wont copy css/scss files I have in the src/ folder.  Is there a way to make it copy them as well?

Comment: Babel's function is processing `js` files. Use `cp` for copying. Better yet, make a gulpfile.

Comment: disagree 100%, babel should include functionality for moving non-js files as this is necessary functionality for >50% of use cases

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Babel has the [copy files](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#copy-files) option for this:

```
babel src --out-dir lib --copy-files
```

*Note: It is true that babels primary purpose is to process javascript files, but babel's big suite of tools these day often makes it unnecessary to go for more complex build script setups as `gulp` and alike.
A gulp-less setup could be adding this to `packages.json`:*

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "*",
    "babel-cli": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "babel --watch src --out-dir lib --source-maps inline --copy-files",
    "build": "babel src --out-dir lib --source-maps inline --copy-files" 
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: this worked, almost, except it didn't copy a jsx file :/

Comment: Could it be you have not added the react preset?

Comment: well, if the react preset is not installed it should still move the file right? :) it did neither, I filed an issue with babel, otherwise this did work and I upvoted :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. Found that the change log (https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) states a bug about this is fixed in version 5.8.13-5.8.20: Fix bug where files that babel can compile weren't being written when ignored with the --copy-files flag.

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to do this by using the ncp module

```
npm install ncp
```

This module is basically like a cp except it works on

This isn't a global module, so to run this we use

```
node -e \"require('ncp').ncp('./src', './lib')\" && babel src --out-dir lib
```